# Set textfield format as IP

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I am writing a program for users to adjust their IP setting.

Just like the system build in tool.

[image]

How can I filter user input in IP format timely?

I have tried using formatter and set textField.formatter but it does not work.

Sample setting in below:

```
var filter = NumberFormatter()
filter.numberstyle = .none
filter.format = "###.###.###.###"
...
textField.formatter = filter
```

Comment: What exactly do you expect and what exactly happens "it does not work"?

Comment: IP addresses can have a different format than the what you have set. It's possible to have 1 or 2 digits in a section.

Comment: the OS doesn't do any formatting to the string while you are typing it. It only checks it the text field it is in a valid format

Comment: I suspect the input should be decimal number with "." only, but it still accepts characters.

Comment: Create a custom subclass of `NSFormatter` or create a subclass of `NSTextField` and implement `- (BOOL)textView:(NSTextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)affectedCharRange replacementString:(NSString *)replacementString`.